# Is there an alternative to MD5 hashing when the input is public?

Tags: hash, md5

I have a database of similar integers by the fact that they all share the same first 3 numbers:

```
7537463746
7536735325
7538236775
7538273826
...
```

Each one is associated to a user, and they are all almost exposed to the public, meaning they are sent as a sort of peer discovery, but not directly shared. I don't want the bare integer to be accessible, so I thought about hashing them with a *one-way* hashing function like [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

Since the output is not reversible like encryption or compression algorithm do, it looks great. But there's a problem; Getting the integer database is easy and inevitable, so looping through them, hashing the loop results and comparing all the hashes to the ones sent through peer communication is going to be a trivial job for malicious users.

The schema is something like this:

```
user1[hash(integer1),hash(integer2)...] -> |server hash database| ->
                                                                    ↓
                                                                    ↓
                                               hash(integer1) = user8
                                              hash(integer2) = user40
```

A malicious user will get user1 integers data by social engineering or other means and hash all of them to see if they're in the database by adding them to his peers data.

Now, is there any hashing algorithm to avoid this type of situation? I need the peers to communicate without giving out their integers data but still both mutually associate the same integer to a unique hash. In alternative, is key signing the only solution? I would like to avoid it since it will make the whole system slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about salting your MD5? What that means is that you have some sort of secret key that only your application knows. This is actually always a good practice. So rather than doing this...

```
md5($userId)
```

You would append the "salt" inside of the MD5 like this...

```
md5($userId . 'this is a secret shhh!')
```

Now they can't get the integer from the MD5.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case I don't think it adds any sort of actual protection. Even if my application was heavily obfuscated and closed source, anyone with a little time could disassemble it and get the secret key. For the attacker it would only be a matter of hashing the integers with the found salt.

Comment: Another option is to give out a unique token instead of the user id. The client would authenticate and you'd give them back a uniquely generated token. And they give you that token which you look up in whatever storage... session, hash table/cache, or database to verify and get their real user id.